# How do I get "rvm system" to be used in new consoles?

Tags: ruby, rvm

I've got two versions of ruby installed, the latest using RVM.

How do I get "rvm system" to be "remembered"  so when I open a new terminal I don't have to remember to run it to get the Ruby version I want/need.

Comment: Dependss on the terminal you use. You'll have to add it to the shell environment , for bash that would be .bash_profile. See the documentation http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/#explained

Answer (score 3, accepted):

run:

```
rvm --default use system
```

or:

```
rvm alias delete default
```

Comment: just a minor change to make it work => "rvm --default use system"

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to [RVM installation instructions](http://beginrescueend.com/rvm/install/)
2. Scroll down to **"2. Load RVM into your shell sessions as a function"**
3. You'll see the following command to modify your `.bash_profile`

`user$ echo '[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function' >> ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: this task is now automated and can be run during update `rvm get head --auto`